# find file with wild card matching

Tags: node.js

In node.js, can I list files with wild card matching like

```
fs.readdirSync('C:/tmp/*.csv')?
```

I did not find the information on wild card matching from the [fs documention](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.3.1/api/fs.html#fs.readFileSync).

Comment: https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob

Answer (score 110, accepted):

This is *not* covered by Node core. The [glob](https://npmjs.org/package/glob) module should be capable of achieving this.

### Setup

```bash
npm i glob
```

### Usage

```js
var glob = require("glob")

// options is optional
glob("**/*.js", options, function(er, files) {
  // files is an array of filenames.
  // If the `nonull` option is set, and nothing
  // was found, then files is ["**/*.js"]
  // er is an error object or null.
})
```

---

Comment: It is not better. Better is getting people using the resources associated with the topic. In this case, learning to use NPM/npmjs.org.

Comment: Thanks. upvoted. It seems that node.js people have very high standard on Q/A here.

Comment: It's not necessarily a Node thing, I feel like it is better to point out resources that can be used in the future rather than just showing someone how to do something. I do the same with MDN for straight JS questions.

Comment: @MorganARR: I was just following policy. Feel free to re-edit. The review system will do it's work. By the way: edits made through the review page are not going for +2.

Comment: In case you are looking for a synchronous solution the mentioned glob library above also has a sync method https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob#globsyncpattern-options

Comment: @MorganARRAllen While I agree that folks should use the linked resources, it's also part of the standard on Stackoverflow to include a sample of what you're describing in your answer.  I tend to do both, as this answer does after edits, having both the link as well as a code snippet.  Links can be broken over time, after all.

Comment: Windows users please note: UNC paths are unsupported in glob as of 12/20/2016

Comment: Thank you, @morgan. Helped me heaps.

Answer (score 163):

If you don't want to add a new dependency to your project (like `glob`), you can use plain js/node functions, like:

```
var files = fs.readdirSync('C:/tmp').filter(fn => fn.endsWith('.csv'));
```

`Regex` may help in more complex comparisons

Comment: Great solution! The glob libraries that I've checked, also use `readdirSync()` and parse the results. But in most cases, a 1-line solution is faster instead of adding a new dependency to the project

Comment: @Philipp a reason people may rather use `glob` would be if they had a config or `.env` that specifies a pattern to search on.

Answer (score 12):

If glob is not quite what you want, or a little confusing, there is also [glob-fs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/glob-fs). The documentation covers many usage scenarios with examples.

```
// sync 
var files = glob.readdirSync('*.js', {});

// async 
glob.readdir('*.js', function(err, files) {
  console.log(files);
});

// stream 
glob.readdirStream('*.js', {})
  .on('data', function(file) {
    console.log(file);
  });

// promise 
glob.readdirPromise('*.js')
  .then(function(files) {
    console.log(file);
  });
```

Comment: Unfortunately glob-fs is not working well with wild cards. See https://github.com/micromatch/glob-fs/issues/22

Comment: @GokceAkcan The post was made before the bug was introduced, but it would probably be better to find something more current. There haven't been any package updates since 2017.

Answer (score 7):

Pretty straightforward with [match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) out of the box

```
import fs from 'fs'

fs.readdirSync('C:/tmp/').filter((allFilesPaths:string) => 
    allFilesPaths.match(/\.csv$/) !== null)
```

Answer (score 3):

Just in case you want to search files by regex (for complex matches), then consider using [file-regex](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-regex), which supports recursive search and concurrency control (for faster results).

Sample usage

```
import FindFiles from 'file-regex'

// This will find all the files with extension .js
// in the given directory
const result = await FindFiles(__dirname, /\.js$/);
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score -6):

dont reinvent the wheel, if you are on *nix the `ls` tool can easily do this ([node api docs](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback))

```
var options = {
  cwd: process.cwd(),
}
require('child_process')
.exec('ls -1 *.csv', options, function(err, stdout, stderr){
  if(err){ console.log(stderr); throw err };
  // remove any trailing newline, otherwise last element will be "":
  stdout = stdout.replace(/\n$/, '');
  var files = stdout.split('\n');
});
```

Comment: What if it's a Windows PC?

Comment: i have never tried but you can attempt a similar result with the windows `dir /B` command, you may also need to split on `\r\n`, not positive

Comment: I strongly against this way of doing things. Invoking command line tools from program code and parsing the result will turn out into maintenance disaster. I inherited project like this once.

Comment: I object to the downvote; certainly there are use cases where `glob` or some other module would be preferable (e.g. if you want to deploy across many platforms and are unsure about whether `ls` will behave the same,) but I don't consider my answer sloppy or "clearly or dangerously incorrect". ["Use your downvotes whenever you encounter an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect."](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down)

Comment: This may be a practical solution but it's not THE solution at all. It's not Node.js-related.

Comment: I agree that this isn't a good solution, but it is a solution!
and sometimes, invoking shell command is all we have, so it is good to see it once in a while. (upvote to correct the wrong)

Comment: What if the user is on an _unconventional_ Linux distribution and `ls` generates funny log? What if the user aliased `ls` to something else? What if the user runs other stuff that write to `stdout` at the same time this block runs? The list goes on and on...I think this answer deserves a downvote, in that it's _perhaps dangerously incorrect_.

Comment: I have nothing against calling the shell sometimes, but parsing `ls` is not always the best idea either: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead
So, I still think this answer is valid and usable, but under rare circumstances.