# Looping through files in a folder Node.JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, loops, fs

I am trying to loop through and pick up files in a directory, but I have some trouble implementing it. How to pull in multiple files and then move them to another folder?

```
var dirname = 'C:/FolderwithFiles';
console.log("Going to get file info!");
fs.stat(dirname, function (err, stats) {
    if (err) {
        return console.error(err);
    }
    console.log(stats);
    console.log("Got file info successfully!");

    // Check file type
    console.log("isFile ? " + stats.isFile());
    console.log("isDirectory ? " + stats.isDirectory());
});
```

Comment: Thanks but yes i know,. I looked at the API and had trouble that's why i am here

Answer (score 157, accepted):

### Older answer with callbacks

You want to use the [fs.readdir](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdir_path_callback) function to get the directory contents and the [fs.rename](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_rename_oldpath_newpath_callback) function to actually do the renaming. Both these functions have synchronous versions if you *need* to wait for them to finishing before running the code afterwards.

I wrote a quick script that does what you described.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
// In newer Node.js versions where process is already global this isn't necessary.
var process = require("process");

var moveFrom = "/home/mike/dev/node/sonar/moveme";
var moveTo = "/home/mike/dev/node/sonar/tome"

// Loop through all the files in the temp directory
fs.readdir(moveFrom, function (err, files) {
  if (err) {
    console.error("Could not list the directory.", err);
    process.exit(1);
  }

  files.forEach(function (file, index) {
    // Make one pass and make the file complete
    var fromPath = path.join(moveFrom, file);
    var toPath = path.join(moveTo, file);

    fs.stat(fromPath, function (error, stat) {
      if (error) {
        console.error("Error stating file.", error);
        return;
      }

      if (stat.isFile())
        console.log("'%s' is a file.", fromPath);
      else if (stat.isDirectory())
        console.log("'%s' is a directory.", fromPath);

      fs.rename(fromPath, toPath, function (error) {
        if (error) {
          console.error("File moving error.", error);
        } else {
          console.log("Moved file '%s' to '%s'.", fromPath, toPath);
        }
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Tested on my local machine.

```
node testme.js 
'/home/mike/dev/node/sonar/moveme/hello' is a file.
'/home/mike/dev/node/sonar/moveme/test' is a directory.
'/home/mike/dev/node/sonar/moveme/test2' is a directory.
'/home/mike/dev/node/sonar/moveme/test23' is a directory.
'/home/mike/dev/node/sonar/moveme/test234' is a directory.
Moved file '/home/mike/dev/node/sonar/moveme/hello' to '/home/mike/dev/node/sonar/tome/hello'.
Moved file '/home/mike/dev/node/sonar/moveme/test' to '/home/mike/dev/node/sonar/tome/test'.
Moved file '/home/mike/dev/node/sonar/moveme/test2' to '/home/mike/dev/node/sonar/tome/test2'.
Moved file '/home/mike/dev/node/sonar/moveme/test23' to '/home/mike/dev/node/sonar/tome/test23'.
Moved file '/home/mike/dev/node/sonar/moveme/test234' to '/home/mike/dev/node/sonar/tome/test234'.
```

### Update: fs.promises functions with async/await

Inspired by ma11hew28's answer ([shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59042581/3282410)), here is the same thing as above but with the async functions in [fs.promises](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_promises_api). As noted by ma11hew28, this may have memory limitations versus [fs.promises.opendir](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fspromises_opendir_path_options) added in v12.12.0.

Quick code below.

```js
//jshint esversion:8
//jshint node:true
const fs = require( 'fs' );
const path = require( 'path' );

const moveFrom = "/tmp/movefrom";
const moveTo = "/tmp/moveto";

// Make an async function that gets executed immediately
(async ()=>{
    // Our starting point
    try {
        // Get the files as an array
        const files = await fs.promises.readdir( moveFrom );

        // Loop them all with the new for...of
        for( const file of files ) {
            // Get the full paths
            const fromPath = path.join( moveFrom, file );
            const toPath = path.join( moveTo, file );

            // Stat the file to see if we have a file or dir
            const stat = await fs.promises.stat( fromPath );

            if( stat.isFile() )
                console.log( "'%s' is a file.", fromPath );
            else if( stat.isDirectory() )
                console.log( "'%s' is a directory.", fromPath );

            // Now move async
            await fs.promises.rename( fromPath, toPath );

            // Log because we're crazy
            console.log( "Moved '%s'->'%s'", fromPath, toPath );
        } // End for...of
    }
    catch( e ) {
        // Catch anything bad that happens
        console.error( "We've thrown! Whoops!", e );
    }

})(); // Wrap in parenthesis and call now
```

Comment: For completeness of the example the following lines exist prior: var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');

Comment: process is a global object. you don't have to require it. Otherwise nice and thanks!

Comment: It used it be in previous versions that you did. It used to need to be referenced by "global.process" and the required file exposes it. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/21320251/161457 if you need wildcards.

Comment: The only concern I have with this solution is that there is no control over the flow of the application. If this is important to your application - you might consider using a [promise](https://github.com/kriskowal/q) chain.

Answer (score 44):

[`fs.readdir(path[, options], callback)`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdir_path_options_callback) (which Mikey A. Leonetti used in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32511953/242933)) and its variants ([`fsPromises.readdir(path[, options])`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fspromises_readdir_path_options) and [`fs.readdirSync(path[, options])`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdirsync_path_options)) each reads all of a directory's entries into memory at once. That's good for most cases, but if the directory has very many entries and/or you want to lower your application's memory footprint, you could instead iterate over the directory's entries one at a time.

#### Asynchronously

Directories are async iterable, so you could do something like this:

```
const fs = require('fs')

async function ls(path) {
  const dir = await fs.promises.opendir(path)
  for await (const dirent of dir) {
    console.log(dirent.name)
  }
}

ls('.').catch(console.error)
```

Or, you could use [`dir.read()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_dir_read) and/or [`dir.read(callback)`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_dir_read_callback) directly.

#### Synchronously

Directories aren't sync iterable, but you could use [`dir.readSync()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_dir_readsync) directly. For example:

```
const fs = require('fs')

const dir = fs.opendirSync('.')
let dirent
while ((dirent = dir.readSync()) !== null) {
  console.log(dirent.name)
}
dir.closeSync()
```

Or, you could make directories sync iterable. For example:

```
const fs = require('fs')

function makeDirectoriesSyncIterable() {
  const p = fs.Dir.prototype
  if (p.hasOwnProperty(Symbol.iterator)) { return }
  const entriesSync = function* () {
    try {
      let dirent
      while ((dirent = this.readSync()) !== null) { yield dirent }
    } finally { this.closeSync() }
  }
  if (!p.hasOwnProperty(entriesSync)) { p.entriesSync = entriesSync }
  Object.defineProperty(p, Symbol.iterator, {
    configurable: true,
    enumerable: false,
    value: entriesSync,
    writable: true
  })
}
makeDirectoriesSyncIterable()
```

And then, you could do something like this:

```
const dir = fs.opendirSync('.')
for (const dirent of dir) {
  console.log(dirent.name)
}
```

---

Note: "In busy processes, use the asynchronous versions of these calls. The synchronous versions will block the entire process until they complete, halting all connections."

References:

- [Node.js Documentation: File System: `Class fs.Dir`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_class_fs_dir)
- [Node.js source code: `fs.Dir`](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/internal/fs/dir.js)
- [GitHub: nodejs/node: Issues: streaming / iterative fs.readdir #583](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/583)

Comment: fs.promises... - nice one

Comment: FWIW, the for await requires node 10.0.0+ or 8.10.0+ with --harmony-async-iteration

Comment: Note that `fs.opendir` and variants were introduced on `v12.12.0` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60247493/typeerror-opendirsync-is-not-a-function

Comment: FYI if someone else starts wondering if you need to manually `await dir.close()`, the answer is no: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63840108/1114901

Answer (score 9):

Read all folders in a directory

```
  const readAllFolder = (dirMain) => {
  const readDirMain = fs.readdirSync(dirMain);

  console.log(dirMain);
  console.log(readDirMain);

  readDirMain.forEach((dirNext) => {
    console.log(dirNext, fs.lstatSync(dirMain + "/" + dirNext).isDirectory());
    if (fs.lstatSync(dirMain + "/" + dirNext).isDirectory()) {
      readAllFolder(dirMain + "/" + dirNext);
    } 
  });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The answers provided are for a single folder. Here is an asynchronous implementation for multiple folders where all the folders are processed simultaneously but the smaller folders or files gets completed first.

*Please comment if you have any feedback*

**Asynchronously Multiple Folders**

```
const fs = require('fs')
const util = require('util')
const path = require('path')

// Multiple folders list
const in_dir_list = [
  'Folder 1 Large',
  'Folder 2 Small', // small folder and files will complete first
  'Folder 3 Extra Large'
]

// BEST PRACTICES: (1) Faster folder list For loop has to be outside async_capture_callback functions for async to make sense
//                 (2) Slower Read Write or I/O processes best be contained in an async_capture_callback functions because these processes are slower than for loop events and faster completed items get callback-ed out first 

for (i = 0; i < in_dir_list.length; i++) {
  var in_dir = in_dir_list[i]

  // function is created (see below) so each folder is processed asynchronously for readFile_async that follows
  readdir_async_capture(in_dir, function(files_path) {
    console.log("Processing folders asynchronously ...")

    for (j = 0; j < files_path.length; j++) {
      file_path = files_path[j]
      file = file_path.substr(file_path.lastIndexOf("/") + 1, file_path.length)

      // function is created (see below) so all files are read simultaneously but the smallest file will be completed first and get callback-ed first 
      readFile_async_capture(file_path, file, function(file_string) {
        try {
          console.log(file_path)
          console.log(file_string)
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(error)
          console.log("System exiting first to catch error if not async will continue...")
          process.exit()
        }
      })
    }
  })
}

// fs.readdir async_capture function to deal with asynchronous code above
function readdir_async_capture(in_dir, callback) {
  fs.readdir(in_dir, function(error, files) {
    if (error) { return console.log(error) }
    files_path = files.map(function(x) { return path.join(in_dir, x) })
    callback(files_path)
  })
}

// fs.readFile async_capture function to deal with asynchronous code above
function readFile_async_capture(file_path, file, callback) {
  fs.readFile(file_path, function(error, data) {
    if (error) { return console.log(error) }
    file_string = data.toString()
    callback(file_string)
  })
}
```