# Webpack how to cache bust angular-translate with $translatePartialLoader?

Tags: javascript, json, webpack

```
"webpack": "^2.7.0"
```

I'm trying to add a hash to our translation files in order to cache bust when deploying. I've managed to extract the json and add a hash and output it to a folder and is good with the world.

But, my unhashed json is still under there original folders after building. I understand that we don't need to add a loader for json as it already has means of handling importing, so my question would be how do I clean out the json that's already been processed?

my folder structure is as follows

```
src/
   app/
     module-name/
        /translations
         en.json
         fn.json
     module-name/
        /translations
         en.json
         fn.json
     //ect...
```

I used the CopyWebpackPlugin to get the json and hash is there maybe an option ive missed that cleans out the process'd files? or maybe i'm approaching this the incorrect way.

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const conf = require('./gulp.conf');
const path = require('path');

const VersionFile = require('webpack-version-file');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const pkg = require('../package.json');
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');

module.exports = {
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'eslint-loader',
        enforce: 'pre'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(css|scss)$/,
        loaders: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          fallback: 'style-loader',
          use: 'css-loader?minimize!resolve-url-loader!sass-loader?sourceMap!postcss-loader'
        })
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          regExp: /\/([a-z0-9]+)\/[a-z0-9]+\.json$/,
          name: '[name]-[hash].[ext]'
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loaders: [
          'ng-annotate-loader',
          'babel-loader'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        loaders: [
          'html-loader'
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: conf.path.src('index.html')
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      output: {comments: false},
      compress: {unused: true, dead_code: true, warnings: false} // eslint-disable-line camelcase
    }),
    new ExtractTextPlugin('index-[contenthash].css'),
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({name: 'vendor'}),
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
      options: {
        postcss: () => [autoprefixer]
      }
    }),
    new webpack.HashedModuleIdsPlugin(),
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([{
      from: 'src/app/**/*.json',
      to: 'translations/[name]-[hash].[ext]'
    }]),
    new VersionFile({
      output: `${conf.paths.dist}/version.txt`,
      verbose: true
    })
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.join(process.cwd(), conf.paths.dist),
    filename: '[name]-[hash].js'
  },
  entry: {
    app: [`./${conf.path.src('app/app.module.js')}`],
    vendor: Object.keys(pkg.dependencies)
  },
  node: {
    fs: 'empty',
    /* eslint-disable camelcase */
    child_process: 'empty'
  }
};
```

Or to similfy the question, how can i add a hash to json files? and the following code doesn't seem to do anything.

```
   {
       test: /\.json$/,
       loader: 'file-loader',
       options: {
         name: '[name]-[hash].[ext]'
       }
   }
```

[image: example of the translations being in both locations]

**EDIT:**

so it seems like my json loader doesnt pick up the translation files as they're dynamicly imported like so how:

```
  $translateProvider.useLoader('$translatePartialLoader', {
    urlTemplate: 'app/{part}/translations/{lang}.json'
  });
```

do you handle cases like this?

Comment: In CopyWebpackPlugin you can specify the path `to: path.join(process.cwd(), conf.path.dist, 'translations/[name]-[hash].[ext]')` it will provide an absolute path to the plugin instead of the current relative path per entry. This will create a `translations` folder at the root of your dist directory

Comment: Yes I can create the translations folder with the hashes just fine will your method remove the old entries?

Comment: @astenmies  Thanks for having a look

Comment: To remove the old entries you can just delete the dist folder and build again

Comment: No so the JSON copied still remains in there original path shown In the screen shot ofc I could do something like exec('-rm /dist/app') or something to that flavour but I was hoping it could be done with the build step if not that's cool

Comment: There's an npm package called `rimraf` that does a `rm -rf`. You may use that to iterate over the files together with `fs` [see looping through files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32511789/looping-through-files-in-a-folder-node-js)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main goal you're trying to do here is telling the browser its a new file when releasing a new version and we can do this fairly easily without having to force webpack to know what files are being used.

in your webpack config add this

```
const pkg = require('../package.json');
//...
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
  __VERSION__: JSON.stringify(pkg.version)
})
```

and where you add your translation files this allows for the browser to know where has been a new release and should update translation files.

```
$translateProvider.useLoader('$translatePartialLoader', {
   urlTemplate: `app/{part}/translations/{lang}.json?v=${__VERSION__}`
});
```