# Angular application by AWS EC2 requires force refresh after update

Tags: angular, caching, browser-cache

I have a legacy Angular application.

- Its Angular version is 1.5.11
- using webpack to build
- and be served by AWS EC2 & apache2

The problem is, **when I update the app,
end users must do force refresh to get the correct update.**

- Webpack changes everytime the main.js file name
- and I launch a new instance everytime, too
- There are no other files except this main.{SOME_HASH}.js file in the build
- There are no CloudFront or other DNS services for this app.

I wonder why the end user side browsers access to the previous build 
even the new build has different file name...

I referred to belows but no lucks yet

- [Angular app has to clear cache after new deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55402751/angular-app-has-to-clear-cache-after-new-deployment)
- [Webpack how to cache bust angular-translate with $translatePartialLoader?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53285407/webpack-how-to-cache-bust-angular-translate-with-translatepartialloader)

It seems, I already do the similar things by webpack.. isn't it?

I have a plan to move to a S3 static hosting and CloudFront,

 But it requires another efforts.

So I want to solve this issue first on the existing structure.
Could you share any advice for me?

Thanks in advance.