# How to write a data as file names in a folder to CSV file using Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv

Anty body did write file names in a folder to the CSV file using javascript

my folder structure is

```
Data
 +IMG
    +test
       -1.png
       -2.png
    +train
       -3.png
       -4.png
```

an output CSV file will be like this

```
Data/IMG/test/1.png     Data/IMG/train/3.png
Data/IMG/test/2.png     Data/IMG/train/4.png
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to loop through all folders and find all files.
You can refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32511953/6798649) to do this.

when you are finding all files' paths, you can write these paths in a string for the csv file:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

let csvStr = "";

async function loop(startPath) {
    // Our starting point
    try {
        // Get the files as an array
        const files = await fs.promises.readdir(startPath);

        // Loop them all with the new for...of
        for (const file of files) {
            // Get the full paths
            const currentPath = path.join(startPath, file);

            // Stat the file to see if we have a file or dir
            const stat = await fs.promises.stat(currentPath);

            if (stat.isFile()) {
                console.log("'%s' is a file.", currentPath);
                // put the file into csv string
                csvStr += currentPath + ", "
            } else if (stat.isDirectory()) {
                console.log("'%s' is a directory.", currentPath);
                // enter the dictionary and loop
                await loop(currentPath);
            }

        } // End for...of
    } catch (e) {
        // Catch anything bad that happens
        console.error("We've thrown! Whoops!", e);
    }

}

// Make an async function that gets executed immediately
(async () => {
    // start loop from the path where you run node
    await loop("./");

    fs.writeFileSync("your.csv", csvStr);
})();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply I am new to js can you explain a bit more or make the code

Comment: `fromPath` is the inner loop is the current position in the folders which should be a file's path or a dictionary's path. You want to find all files, so we just need the files' paths. We can collect the files paths' name for CSV, so I add `csvStr += fromPath + ", "`. `,` is for the CSV seperator.

Comment: can you provide a full of code bro? I have tried but not get successful

Comment: there are always commas in CSV (Comma-separated values) file, so I cannot understand your given sample output (no commas). Or, I guess you just want the `test` to be a column and `train` to be another one? I thought it's not too hard, since you have already know how to get all files name. What you need to do is adding some `if else`, would you like to try yourself?