# How extract file names in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I have a project, that responds with items that user searches. Each item has its type and meta number (404-0. 404 for type, 0 for meta). Also I have a folder with item images, image name corresponds to the type and meta number of the item. How can I get through all image folder and extract only its name (404-0 without .img) ?

```
[
  {
    "type": 0,
    "meta": 0,
    "name": "Air",
    "text_type": "air"
  },
  {
    "type": 1,
    "meta": 0,
    "name": "Stone",
    "text_type": "stone"
  },
  {
    "type": 1,
    "meta": 1,
    "name": "Granite",
    "text_type": "stone"
  },
  {
    "type": 1,
    "meta": 2,
    "name": "Polished Granite",
    "text_type": "stone"
  },
  {
    "type": 1,
    "meta": 3,
    "name": "Diorite",
    "text_type": "stone"
  },
  {
    "type": 1,
    "meta": 4,
    "name": "Polished Diorite",
    "text_type": "stone"
  }
]
```

[image folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M3z1K.png)

Comment: You need to use the fs module or the global pattern. https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html I'm pretty sure, however, that with a bit more effort you could've come up with a slightly preciser scenario, it doesn't really look like you put much effort before asking, in my opinion.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Looping through files in a folder Node.JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32511789/looping-through-files-in-a-folder-node-js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried?
`const files = fs.readdirSync('path/to/folder').map(name => name.split('.')[0])`