# How do I pass an incomplete partial path to fs.existsSync in Node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I would like to call something like `fs.existsSync('*.zip')` to check for all `.zip` files. However, from my tests it seems to only work with exact paths and filenames. Do I have to grab all file names from the directory first, or is there a way to do it in one line with `existsSync` and some kind of regex?

Thanks!

Comment: node.js does not come with support for file wildcard listing.  There are many packages to do that for you.

Comment: Dang, ok. Thanks! I think I will just read all the filenames in the directory I know it's in, and do my own pattern matching.

Comment: You can grab a pre-built module for it and use it with only a couple lines of code.  Search google for `npm wildcard`.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21319602/find-file-with-wild-card-matching