# NodeJS find file that starts with name.* in directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

My NodeJS Server will get a request /profile_avatars/username
and will have to look for a file in the directory that starts with "username.*",
and therefore will response with this file.
I thought about using fs.readdir, and iterate trough the array of all filenames.
But it unneccessarily lists all files in the array. Not effective for very large directories with 100GB+ files.
Any alternative solutions?

Comment: There's a similar question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21319602/find-file-with-wild-card-matching.  In your case, watch out for a security issue if someone supplies "../.." for a username!  They could traverse your server's file system.

Comment: you can create a data structures avl-tree with key 'user'  and keep in each node the path of the file to recover according to that given key.

Comment: BTW one trick that might mitigate the problem is to have a directory structure like "users/a/" and "users/b" and so forth -- that will reduce the number of files in a directory.  You can even subdivide into "users/a/aa" and "users/a/ab" so a user called "abe" would go into the "users/a/ab" folder.

Comment: Oh thanks for mentioning the insecurity! And that subdividing is a smart way to keep readdir small. Might look into avl-tree if its left to be to make it efficient.

Comment: @user2740650 maybe instead of sendingFile directly I should always redirect them to the static folder/file of the file. Would that solve the security problem?

Comment: I'm not sure I understood, but to mitigate the security issue, you'd have to make sure all user names are only valid characters that aren't special characters like "." and "/".  Basically, don't trust anything coming from outside, including the url.  If you get some that doesn't contain only "regular" characters, then reject the request (eg. give a 404 or something).

Comment: Can't you just known the whole filename?  Why do you not know what the file extension will be?  What are you supposed to do if there's more than one file matching `username.*`?

Comment: @jfriend00 I try to avoid database when users upload avatar and want to allow every image/* format. And users do not know what extension other users have, so I keep it simpel /username -> /username.jpg ect. I'm not sure if database would be better option, but everytime user uploads nodejs will look if exists and unlink.

Comment: OK, I was just trying to avoid having the scan the whole directory every time you want to serve the file, but I guess you can't if that's the architecture.

Comment: I mean I could easily implement database part too, but then its up to performance: database vs my idea.