# javascript subfolder read files

Tags: javascript

How can i make the bottom part of code work so the files in subdir are found?

```
// example filepath: ./src/commands/commandFile.js 

const commandFiles = fs
  .readdirSync("./src/commands")
  .filter((file) => file.endsWith(".js"));

^^
//This top part works when files are not in subdir
  
// change to filepath/subdir
// example filepath: ./src/commands/testCommand/commandFile.js

const commandFiles = fs
  .readdirSync("./src/commands/*")
  .filter((file) => file.endsWith(".js"));
```

Comment: Wildcard search is not supported.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [find file with wild card matching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21319602/find-file-with-wild-card-matching)

Comment: @XTK are you trying to list all the files recursively?