# Find first file with given filename

Tags: javascript, node.js

Hello I am trying to find first file with given filename ( piece of filename ).

It works fine but it take a while to take result

There is code

```
const fs = require("fs");

const dirCheckIn =
    "\\\\192.168.2.4\\Photos";


exports.checkUploadedFiles = (req, res) => {
    let fileName = req.params.filename;

    const getAllFiles = function (dirPath, arrayOfFiles) {
        files = fs.readdirSync(dirPath);

        arrayOfFiles = arrayOfFiles || [];

        files.forEach(function (file) {
            if (fs.statSync(dirPath + "/" + file).isDirectory()) {
                arrayOfFiles = getAllFiles(dirPath + "/" + file, arrayOfFiles);
            } else {
                arrayOfFiles.push(file);
            }
        });

        return arrayOfFiles;
    };

    const uploadedFiles = getAllFiles(inventDirCheckIn);
    console.log(uploadedFiles)
    let result = uploadedFiles.find(
        (result) => result.startsWith(fileName));

    if (!result) {
        res.send('nothing found')
    } else if (result) {
        res.send(result)
    }

}
```

It works fine but for example if I have over 7000 photos it takes about 5 sec to get result.
Maybe there is smarter solution?

How can I make it in better way? I want to check if file is uploaded into dir Photos.
I got simple api route `/api/getUploadedFiles/:filename`

Also I want use `startsWith` because sometimes I do not know full name of file

Comment: I think you should try to open the file with `fs.open()`, `fs.readFile()` or `fs.writeFile()` and then handle the error. If it exists, it's going to open, if it doesn't, deal with the error. 

Source: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fsstatpath-options-callback
>Using fs.stat() to check for the existence of a file before calling fs.open(), fs.readFile() or fs.writeFile() is not recommended. Instead, user code should open/read/write the file directly and handle the error raised if the file is not available.

Comment: I do not want to open it. I want only true or false if exist true else false

Comment: 'Using `fs.stat()` to check for the existence' - I think this should do the job?

Comment: or 'To check if a file exists without manipulating it afterwards, `fs.access()` is recommended.'

Comment: This [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70003520/5156280) seems good and fast.

Comment: I'll test it @TGrif

Comment: Ok I'll check it also @matzar

Answer (score 0):

```js
/**
 *
 * @param filePath path to file which is to be checked if it exists.
 */
private checkFileExistsSync(filePath: string) {
  let flag = true;
  try {
    fs.accessSync(filePath, fs.constants.F_OK);
  } catch (e) {
    flag = false;
  }
  return flag;
}

// Example usage
// path to the file
const dirCheckIn =
    "\\\\192.168.2.4\\Photos";
    
if (checkFileExistsSync(dirCheckIn)) {
  // if the file exists do something...
}

if (!checkFileExistsSync(dirCheckIn)) {
  // if the file doesn't exists do something...
}
```