# How to verify if a file is downloaded with a particular extension instead of whole name?

Tags: javascript, cypress

I created test that:

1. erase existing download directory (cypress/download)
2. Downloading a file.pdf/csv/txt/and so on...
3. Makes an assertion and in order to do that you have to provide expected filename for instance 'correctFile.pdf' and cypress will match this expected name with filename that has been downloaded in 'cypress/download'.
4. erase existing download directory (cypress/download)

**cypress/download**
`TEST.pdf`

**TEST:**
`

```
it.only("should downloads file", () => {
    cy.task('deleteDirectory', downloadsFolder); // deleting download directory
    cy.get("downloadButton").click(); // downloading 'TEST.pdf' file
    cy.task('isExistDownloadedFile', 'TEST.pdf').should('equal', true); // assertion
    cy.task('deleteDirectory', downloadsFolder); // deleting download directory
  })
```

`

**plugins/index.js**
`

```
**--snip--**

const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const downloadDirectory = path.join(__dirname, '..', 'downloads');
    
const findDownloadedFile = (filename) => {
  **const FileName = `${downloadDirectory}/${filename}`;**
  const contents = fs.existsSync(FileName);
  return contents;
};
    
const hasFile = (filename, ms) => {
  const delay = 10;
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (ms < 0) {
      return reject(
        new Error(`Could not find any file ${downloadDirectory}/${filename}`)
      );
    }
    const found = findDownloadedFile(filename);
    if (found) {
      return resolve(true);
    }
    setTimeout(() => {
      hasFile(filename, ms - delay).then(resolve, reject);
    }, delay);
  });
};

**--snip--**

// find downloaded file and match the name of that file with the expected filename
  on('task', {
    isExistDownloadedFile(filename, ms = 4000) {
      return hasFile(filename, ms);
    },
  });
  return config;
```

`

**My question:**
Now I can assert only entire file name e.g.
`TEST.pdf (downloaded) equal to TEST.pdf (expected)` RESULT: PASSED
but how can I make that my program will also accept some characters, like only extension for instance:
`TEST.pdf (downloaded) contains .pdf (expected)` RESULT: PASSED

Comment: Consider using [the promise-based FileSystem API](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#promises-api) available in versions of Node since 10.0. That way you can remove the promise constructor in `hasFile`. I would probably change it to use [`readdir`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fspromisesreaddirpath-options) and [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some). You can do either check, depending on the function passed to `some`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install [glob](https://www.npmjs.com/package/glob) and use it in place of `fs.existsSync()`

**plugins/index.js**

```js
...
const glob = require("glob");

const findDownloadedFile = (filename) => {
  const matches = glob.sync(fileName);
  return (matches.length > 0);
}
```

**test**

```js
// partial name
cy.task('isExistDownloadedFile', '*.pdf').should('equal', true)

// still works with full name
cy.task('isExistDownloadedFile', 'TEST.pdf').should('equal', true)
```

Comment: Great, you can also provide more extensions: '*.+(pdf|txt|csv|docx|xml)'

Answer (score 1):

You could implement something like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51888262/11625850) to filter the results of the entire list of files in the directory.

```js
const findDownloadedFile = (filename) => {
  const files = fs.readDirSync(downloadDirectory).filter((x) => x.includes(filename));
  return files.length
};
```